# Android How to prevent Activity staterd by service stopping the service

Tags: android

I have done a app which has broadcast receiver which starts service on boot up. The service have two threads, one to listen for UDP Packets and other one to process the packets convert them to messages and calls an activity which display the current messages in a list view. These messages will be deleted out of the display by cancellation packets received by the service. Hence only valid messages are displayed. All works well until user closes the activity. When user closes the display activity the service stops and restarts , which causes the any active messages held by service to be lost. How can I prevent service being restarted each time activity is closed or is there a way to stop the user from closing the activity? Please advice.

My Manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mcs.rmsg" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
    <application
    android:name="com.mcs.rmsg.GlobalState"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MsgView"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
        android:name=".mstart"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".udp"
                  />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing display activity class from the app but by creating dummy activity , which does not do anything. Opening and closing this activity does not stop the service. The service receive the UDP Packets and process it when there is valid message it makes audio alert and writes to file. I developed another application to read the messages from file and display on the screen